# How to Select continuous date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

CTE that I have tried:

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT domain_id, 
                startingdate, 
                endingdate 
         FROM   cal 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t.domain_id, 
                cte.startingdate, 
                t.endingdate 
         FROM   cte 
                JOIN cal t 
                  ON cte.domain_id = t.domain_id 
                     AND cte.endingdate = t.startingdate), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                rn = Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         partition BY domain_id, endingdate 
                         ORDER BY domain_id) 
         FROM   cte) 
SELECT domain_id, 
       startingdate, 
       Max(endingdate) enddate 
FROM   cte2 
WHERE  rn = 1 
GROUP  BY domain_id, 
          startingdate 
ORDER  BY domain_id, 
          startingdate; 

SELECT * FROM cal
```

What changes are expected in this code to get the required output

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

[image]

Comment: Use `DATEADD` instead of `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, rather than an rCTE (which is a hidden form of RBAR), I would use a virtualised tally table:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20181101', @EndDate date = '20181201';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
    ),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) AS [Date]
    FROM Tally
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) <= @EndDate)
SELECT [Date]
FROM Dates;
```

However, the best solution is to probably have a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEADD()` as

```
Declare @StartDate Date='2016-06-07'

Declare @EndDate Date='2016-07-10'

;with cte as(

Select @StartDate Date

union all

SELECT dateadd(day, 1, date) FROM cte WHERE dateadd(day, 1, date) <= @EndDate

)
select DATE FROM cte
```